# Eclipse shortcut "debug last debug configuration" (not F11)

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I'm looking for a shortcut to debug the last debug configuration. I know about the existence of <kbd>F11</kbd>, but the problem is, that I want to start debugging the last configuration. <kbd>F11</kbd> runs the debugging of the class currently opened.

I thought it would be easy to find that shortcut on the net, but no luck...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Check the prefs, namely "Run/Debug" -> "Launching" -> "Launch Operation". There you can select what <kbd>F11</kbd> does: Run/Debug the file open in the current editor or use the last launch config again (first option in the last block in the page).

Comment: Still helpful 3 years later... :)

Comment: Still helpful 3 years after that.

Comment: Why is there an underscore 1 in the drop down menu by the little debug icon ? I suspect it's a shortcut key...

Comment: @Stephane Not sure where the underscore comes from but yes, if you open the drop down and press `1` to `9`, then the respective item in the menu will be launched.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I wish there was a keys combination with the 1 so as to skip the mousing to the drop down.

Comment: @Stephane On WIndows: Alt+R (open Run menu), Alt+T (opens the "Run..." item), Alt+Number to select the n-th item.