# eclipse Luna: command "Debug Last Launched" missing (?)

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know what happened to 'Debug last launched' -- using eclipse Luna ( M7 Release - 4.4.0M7 ) on KUbuntu and the command seems to be missing.

There's  'Debug as', or by using the mouse and menu dropdown I can get the functional equivalent, but as I'm debugging, there's no command option to bind a keyboard shortcut to that I can find (such as F11).

e.g. same functionality as in: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fmenus%2Frun%2Fref-dll_debug.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse shortcut "debug last debug configuration" (not F11)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591645/eclipse-shortcut-debug-last-debug-configuration-not-f11)

Comment: Hey greg-449: that was it!!  can I give you credit? Do I close out my question, delete it?

Comment: Just leave the question, it will probably get closed as a duplicate eventually. Duplicates can help people searching for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was *confusing*:   thanks to "greg-449" for the answer

---

Turns out that the command "Debug last launched" is available only once you enable the preference change: 
  Go to >   "Run/Debug" -> "Launching", then see 'Launch Operation', and change it to "Always launch the previous launched application"

At that point, the command for "Debug last launched" will magically appear, and be your default.

This is especially confusing, since only by changing that preference, will the "Debug last launched" command be even available in the "Preferences==>General==>Keys" dialogue (what comes up when you hit 'Control + Shift + L' twice)